# Automatically splinting long images to fit multiple pages in word (2013)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013

I have a few long images that I need to get into word without having them go onto their own pages (separating themselves from the text), ideally having the image split up and go onto multiple pages bellow the text without having to do it manually (as the distance that the first break might happen could change).

I'm using Word 2013.

Comment: AFAIK, Word only works in two dimensions. It cannot handle long images. I'd guess that this isn't what you meant to say.

Comment: I'm with krowe on this one. In word an image is anchored to a paragraph on a page, the image doesn't ever extend past that page the paragraph is on so there isn't much hope of this working as you hoped.

Comment: Well in that case i will just have to split the image up into pieces, one of the images if about 2.5 pages long which is why i was hoping that there was a solution built in :(